# Ayuda con MVC, soy novato u.u

Tags: java

Sáquenme de dudas, por ejemplo al hacer un programa con mvc, pues la vista envía los mensajes al controlador para que este a su vez envíe el mensaje al modelo, entonces en el modelo va la lógica de la aplicación, en el controlador es el puente entre la vista y el modelo, y ps el modelo sólo recibe las acciones hechas por el usuario y da las respuestas respectivas, mi pregunta es la seguiente:
Al realizar una aplicación de escritorio por ejemplo: un login, la persona escribe su usuario y contraseña respectiva, y este viaja al controlador el cuál pedirá al modelo si es correcta o no, pues donde redacto los mensajes que se le regresarán al usuario, por ejemplo contraseña incorrecta, lo redacto en el modelo, controlador o en la vista, me podrín explicar porfavor.

Otra consulta:
Al hacer las validaciones por ejemplo de números, creo en el modelo una clase validadora, el cuál lo llamo en el controlador?, o simplemente lo valido en el modelo, el cuál ps para el ejemplo del login, cuando ingrese la contraseña incorrecta desde el modelo con un método retorne un String con el mensaje.

Si fueran tan amables en responderme y si es con un ejemplo básico sería mejor, gracias.

Comment: para que aprendas mvc, te recomiendo no hacerlo en consola o escritorio, sino en web usando struts 1, u otro framework mvc web, despues te regresas a consola o escritorio, porque sino te va a costar mas trabajo entender mvc, te lo comento porque así fue en mi experiencia. Ademas hay muchos libros de struts 1 por ahi.

Comment: me podrías decir algunos libros porfa...

Comment: http://www.gandhi.com.mx/struts

Comment: http://www.redusers.com/noticias/publicaciones/lpcu090/

Comment: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007713.do

Comment: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003289.do

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

Verás, en un MVC **(Model View Controller, o Modelo Controlador de Vistas)** es un tipo de patrón de diseño, de los cuales hay varios.

MVC se caracteriza por tener un **Controlador** que es encargado de determinar qué **Vista** presentar al usuario, de acuerdo a la acción ejecutada por éste.
En el MVC, cada acción en una Vista es correlacionada a algo que el Controlador debe atender, y dependiendo de la acción, puede hacer peticiones HTTP, agregar un nuevo elemento, y demás.

La Vista es sólo una representación del Modelo, que éste es generalmente una Base de Datos o algo similar.

***En resumen:*** El Modelo es casi siempre una Base de Datos; una Vista es sólo la representación que se le da a la BD; el Controlador interactúa directamente con la Vista para responder a acciones realizadas en ésta, y realiza acciones predeterminadas.

Ahora, para responder a tus preguntas:

- En el primer ejemplo, **(perdona si me equivoco, hace tiempo no trabajo en desktop)** deberías redactar un código de respuesta hacia esos eventos, que éste código modifique un poco la Vista del login en éste caso. Osea, escribes en el Controlador lo que quieres que le suceda a la Vista dependiendo de la validez de las credenciales: Un mensaje, borra los TextFields, etc...
- Si quieres realizar validaciones de algún tipo, debes hacerlo primero en el Controlador, porque éste es justamente eso, el que controla qué datos pasan y modifican algo, *y cuáles no*. Si quieres saber si la contraseña es incorrecta, pues desde el controlador mandas una consulta a la BD y pides la contraseña del usuario, luego tomas la que él ingreso en el login, las comparas y dependiendo del resultado, el Controlador actúa según lo que le digas qué hacer.

Espero que haya podido aclarar un poco tus dudas, te recomiendo leer [éste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference) en SO para saber más.

Comment: Muchas gracias!